# Anonymous Class and Anonymous Thread

Tags: java, multithreading, class

What is the difference between anonymous (class and thread) and normal class/ thread?
Could we track which thread if its anonymous in multi threading?

Thanks

Comment: "anonymous thread" doesn't really make any sense.  A _thread_ is not the same thing as a `Thread` instance.  A `Thread` instance is a Java object---just like any other object except that it happens to have some native methods that you can use to start a _thread_ and manage its life cycle.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An anonymous class of `Thread` is an anonymous class of the `Thread` class. That's all.
It has no relation with the fact the thread is visible and identifiable in the scope of the application.

For example, here `t` is a `Thread` instance identifiable (it is a `Thread`object and it has a name) and so trackable :

```
Thread t = new Thread("myThread"){
        @Override
        public void run() {
          ...
        }       
};
```